# Por que Malaquias é um termo chulo em Portugal?

Tags: origem

Nesta semana recebi alguns memes de Portugal. Em alguns deles havia o nome "Malaquias", que seria, pelo que entendi, um sinônimo chulo para a genitália masculina. Não posso dizer que isto não é dito no Brasil, mas afirmo que nunca ouvi isso antes.

Enfim, por que este nome? De onde vem isso?

Comment: Lol, também não sabia que se usava aqui em Portugal *Malaquias* para designar o membro viril. Mas o que é que um homem não pode chamar ao seu fiel companheiro? Podes partilhar alguns links onde se veja isso? De qualquer modo não me parece chulo; mais talvez uma maneira de evitar um termo chulo.

Comment: Também vi alguns memes postados no facebook, com as mais diversas gírias de significado sexual, supostamente usadas em Portugal, e que nunca ouvi antes.  "Malaquias" é uma delas.  Isso me faz lembrar uma campanha de prevenção da AIDS que ia ser feita pelo Ministério da Saúde há uns 20 anos, e que iria utilizar o nome "Bráulio" para referir-se ao pênis.  Houve uma chuva de reclamações de indivíduos que se chamavam Bráulio e o Ministério acabou mudando o apelido que pretendia dar.  Só aqui mesmo essas besteiras (rs rs)

Comment: @Jacinto claro, pode chamá-lo de vários nomes. Mas é estranho porque encontrei em alguns sites. Alguns exemplos: http://www.memes.com/img/850591 http://www.memes.com/img/985526

Comment: @Centaurus Até hoje tem gente que chama de Braulio. Neste caso foi por causa da campanha, como você bem lembrou.

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido esse termo cá pelo Norte... e já ouvi muita coisa, salvo seja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu já conhecia muitos nomes para o membro viril, mas *Malaquias* foi aqui a primeira vez que vi. E ao fim de um mês, ainda não encontrei ninguém que já conhecesse este uso de *Malaquias*. Eu sou do sul, e o ANeves, que é do norte, diz o mesmo. Aparentemente isto é uma invenção recente e teve uma circulação limitada a piadas e memes na net. Alguns comentadores [neste post com vários memes sobre o *Malaquias*](http://www.naosalvo.com.br/conheca-os-memes-de-portugal-que-farao-seu-malaquias-subir/) são da mesma opinião. O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei na net deste *Malaquias* é apenas de 2014, nestas [*22 formas de os homens dizerem que se vão MASTURBAR*](http://asanedotas.blogspot.pt/2014/11/22-formas-de-os-homens-dizerem-que-se.html).

Agora, porque é que alguém se lembrou de chamar *Malaquias* ao membro viril. Poderá não ser possível responder a essa questão. Mas eu encontrei [esta piada na net](http://ojardineiroejesus.blogs.sapo.pt/55951.html), que circula pelo menos desde 2009, que poderia ter servido de inspiração. Resumindo:

> Numa agência funerária, um funcionário impressiona-se com o tamanho do membro viril de um defunto, o Sr. Malaquias. Decide amputá-lo e preservá-lo. Quando chega a casa, diz à mulher, «Olha o que eu encontrei na funerária!» Ela olha e grita estarrecida, «Oh meu Deus, o Malaquias morreu!». Moral da história: não leves trabalho para casa.

Acho também que *Malaquias* ser um nome invulgar e algo engraçado, como observado na outra resposta, pode ter contribuído. O nome *Malaquias* parece aparecer desproporcionalmente em histórias e posts cómicos na net. Há a história do [cobói Malaquias](http://www.osvigaristas.com.br/piadas/redacao-sobre-sexo-8684.html), outra do [cigano Malaquias (2012)](http://carapaucarapau.blogs.sapo.pt/62114.html); há um blog dedicado às [*Meditações Infecundas de Malaquias Malazartes*](http://filosofilo.blogspot.pt/2005/10/poeminha-do-malaquias.html), e ainda o [fado do Malaquias barbeiro, que vai ao mercado e compra um carneiro.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V99e1peFzfc)

Comment: +1 pela pesquisa. Ajudou bastante, obrigado!

Comment: Jacinto aqui o Grego já ouviu, para variar estou do contra ;)

Comment: E já agora por aqui usa-se q.b. a palavra, para te referires ao pessoal, Malaquias, Zecarias, etc. "Oh Malaquias anda ca car****!".

Comment: @JorgeB. Há quanto tempo é que conheces *Malaquias* como nome para a pila?

Comment: @Jacinto é relativamente recente, mas não te sei dizer. Mas não é muito usado, isso é certo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Lol então estás contra o quê? Eu só disse que não tinha encontrado ninguém que conhecesse esse uso. Agora encontrei-te a ti.

Comment: @Jacinto estou do contra porque parece que vivo num pais diferente do vosso, por isso é que fiz a piada com o grego e com o contra...

Comment: @JorgeB. Pode ser simplesmente das pessoas com quem te dás. Eu não sigo esses memes, e possivelmente as pessoas com quem mais me dou também não.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não tenho reputação para comentar a pergunta, porém deixo aqui os meus dois dedos centavos:

Eu recentemente ando vendo esse termo em alguns memes no brasil, se bem que isso poderia muito bem ser uma influência de portugal.

Eu não tenho certeza em portugal, mas para mim Malaquias é um nome muito engraçado para se referir ao membro masculino. Assim como em outras línguas, pessoas sempre são criativas para criar novos nomes para se referir ao tal. Acho que é só isso, não imagino um significado muito especial em 'Malaquias' além de ser engraçado para mim.

Answer (score 1):

Hoje em dia são feitas traduções automáticas, traduções bastante certas e algumas bastante erradas. Fala-se algo, já existe. E qualquer equívoco passa a ser parte do discurso. E de repente passa a ser parte da linguagem falada. Nós identificamos rapidamente anglicismos. Mas não é só o inglês que é permanentemente aportuguesado.  Visitando um mercado grego, rapidamente se nota que Malaka e Malakias são as palavras brejeiras mais usadas pelos homens gregos de hoje. Muito usadas. Um insulto sim, mas que não parece ofender o visado, palavrão sem o ser, designando alguém que passa a vida a masturbar-se. Eu conheci um senhor no Brasil que era conhecido por Malaka. Explicou-me que essa alcunha quereria dizer "peito forte" e que teria sido um marinheiro grego que lho colocara. Conhecendo bem vários gregos,  a minha interpretação é outra...
Em Portugal, do Sul ao Norte nunca ouvi essa designação para pénis.
Cordialmente
Dias

Answer (score 0):

De facto, aqui em Portugal, o termo Malaquias, utilizado  para designar o membro viril, tem-se vindo a dissipar cada vez mais com o passar dos anos.

A origem deste termo surgiu em contexto popular, tendo vindo a espalhar-se através das típicas piadas Alentejanas e Algarvias.

Como é natural, a revelia do conservadorismo católico veio a ser o causador da dissipação deste termo, que aos poucos foi ocasionando o seu desaparecimento.

Nos últimos anos o termo voltou a reaparecer em meio urbano. Embora sendo comum no meio rural, mantinha-se aos olhos dos citadinos uma expressão desconhecida. E assim como Malaquias surgiu de novo, também o mesmo aconteceu com o termo Mexilhão, utilizado para designar o membro íntimo feminino.

Estas expressões têm vindo a adquirir, até por meio das redes sociais (como os memes) uma posição cada vez mais importante, sendo que se têm vindo a tornar algo cada vez mais natural de se dizer, menos incongruente.

E sim, de facto a piada acima transcrita (por um dos indivíduos que comentaram este post) é realmente um dos motivos pela qual a palavra se veio a espalhar em áreas citadinas e urbanizadas, mas não foi o motivo de inspiração.
Antes pelo contrário, o termo popular Malaquias é que deu origem a este tipo de piadas, uma vez que, e como dito anteriormente, Malaquias é um sobrenome também ele de origem popular (embora hoje em dia seja um sobrenome em desuso).
É esse o motivo das piadas sobre o termo serem também elas de origem popular, já que o sobrenome em si também o era.

Exemplificando agora isto de forma a que se perceba melhor sem que fiquem confusos.
Seria como se no Brasil alguém de minas tivesse o sobrenome Rola, e devido à pronúncia engraçada do sobrenome e há própria figura caricata da pessoa, as pessoas da sua província começassem a criar piadas! Ou por o indivíduo ter um pênis maior do que o normal, ou por andar sempre teso... esse tipo de coisa. Daí surgiriam piadas como "o pênis do Rola isto" ou "o Rola júnior aquilo", e as pessoas começariam a associar a palavra rola a pênis, e começava não tento a ser um sobrenome mas sim um termo sexual com duplo significado.

Tão simples quanto isto.

:)) Português culto aqui a representar a nação eheh

Comment: Ana, bem-vinda à comunidade. Isto é muito interessante, mas para mim faltam pormenores importantes. Como é que sabes isto tudo? Onde e quando é que *malaquias* era termo para pénis? Onde e quando é que circularam essas piadas? As "típicas piadas alentejanas" são as piadas acerca de alentejanos que se contam pelo país todo? "Meio rural" é muito vasto. Eu cresci no meio rural, e antes desta pergunta nunca tinha ouvido este uso de *malaquias*. E lá o conservadorismo católico jamais dissipou coisa alguma. Eu ia à catequesese como toda a criançada da altura (anos 70), o que não nos impedia de ir >>

Comment: >> depois partilhar piadas porcas e de natureza sexual. Conhecia uma beata viúva que tinha cá um repertório... *Malaquias* é sobrenome de origem popular!? Que queres dizer com isso? Malaquias é um nome bíblico, um dos profetas do Antigo Testamento, e também houve um Santo Malaquias. E é usado como nome próprio pelos menos desde o princípio do século XIX.