# Trololó = Troll, LOL, LOL?

Tags: significado, etimologia

De alguns anos para cá, se popularizou no Brasil a expressão "trololó". Mais recentemente tenho visto a frase "troll, LOL, LOL" em inglês. É claro que isso é terreno fértil para "etimologia popular". Então, antes que a lenda se espalhe, como demonstrar que é só uma coincidência? Ou será que eu estou errado, e não é coincidência?

Exemplos de uso:

> Serra se irrita com pergunta sobre ‘kit-gay’ e acusa jornalista de ‘propagar trololó petista’
>   [(UOL, 2012.)](http://eleicoes.uol.com.br/2012/noticias/2012/10/16/serra-se-irrita-com-pergunta-sobre-kit-gay-e-acusa-jornalista-de-propagar-trololo-petista.htm)

Ou, do outro lado da *political divide*,

> Trololó tucano é o mesmo há 20 anos. [(Paulo Henrique Amorim, 2013.)](http://www.conversaafiada.com.br/economia/2013/07/14/trololo-tucano-e-o-mesmo-ha-20-anos)

Comment: Luis, sugiro postar também o significado de "trololó" e o de "troll, LOL, LOL", de acordo com suas entradas nos dicionários.  O significado que "se popularizou" consta nos dicionários ou é um significado novo ?  Eu, pessoalmente, nunca ouvi a expressão.  Vou perguntar aos meus filhos pois pode ser um linguajar de adolescentes e adultos jovens, o que não é o meu caso.

Comment: As definições do dicionário e [uma pesquisa no google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=trolol%C3%B3) podem ajudar a elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: Popularizou-se *trololó* com que significado. Os que eu encontro no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/trolol%C3%B3) quase certamente antecedem o *troll* da internet. Parece ser uma variante de *tralalá* e aparentado com *tiroliro*.

Comment: Trololó é um blá blá blá querendo enganar ou enrolar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O ***trololó*** já cá anda, por escrito, há mais de um século. Os dicionários concordam na origem onomatopaica. O sentido em que é usado nos teus exemplos é o [2 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/trolol%C3%B3) e também o 2 do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), que transcrevo:

> **trololó** *s.m.* **1** música ligeira, fácil de entoar **2** *p. ext. B* conversa vazia, inútil, vã; lero-lero (B) **3** *B infrm.* coisa que aborrece; amolação, inana (B) **4** *B infrm.* conjunto das nádegas ▪ *adj.* **5** que se veste muito bem (diz-se de indivíduo); elegante, frajola (B) ʘ ETIM origem onomatopaica.

O ***trololó*** mais antigo que encontrei foi no revista [*O Malho*, de 1903](http://www.casaruibarbosa.gov.br/omalho/revista.asp?rev=40&ano=1903) (p. 5), onde se refere a um género de teatro musicado ligeiro (reconstruí o que pude da parte ilegível com a ajuda [desta tese de mestrado, p. 33](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22trolol%C3%B3%20do%20Jos%C3%A9%20Ricardo%22&oq=%22trolol%C3%B3%20do%20Jos%C3%A9%20Ricardo%22&gs_l=serp.3...14786.15266.0.16212.2.2.0.0.0.0.139.223.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.6dg2j92upoE)):

[image: *O Malho, nº 20, J]
[“Teatrices”, *O Malho*, nº 40, Rio de Janeiro, 20 de Junho de 1903, p. 5.](http://www.casaruibarbosa.gov.br/omalho/revista.asp?rev=40&ano=1903)

O exemplo seguinte que encontrei refere-se também a este género teatral. É de 1908, por João do Rio no *O Momento Literário*. ([excerto reduzido do original de 1908](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22veiu%20o%20annuncio%22&oq=%22veiu%20o%20annuncio%22&gs_l=serp.3...28230.28230.0.29646.1.1.0.0.0.0.138.138.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.52QsL2ZAIJo) e [texto integral de edição de 2013](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oYpcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&dq=%22trolol%C3%B3%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj02aC2nNbQAhWFtBQKHXdLCKcQ6AEInwEwEQ#v=onepage&q=%22trolol%C3%B3%22&f=false); grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> A decadência do teatro é devida exclusivamente ao jornal e aos próprios escritores dramáticos jornalistas. O público é um animal que se educa. A princípio ia aos teatros bons. Veio o anúncio, o balcão dominou, começaram os incentivos para o ***trololó***. Hoje o público está acostumado e não quer outra cousa.

A aceção ‘conversa vazia’ aparece no Google Books já em 1910, em [Júlia Lopes de Almeida, *Elles e Ellas*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22tro-lol%C3%B3%20tralal%C3%A1%22&oq=%22tro-lol%C3%B3%20tralal%C3%A1%22&gs_l=serp.3...9782.9782.0.12801.1.1.0.0.0.0.72.72.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.Q_5O3aBJYtQ):

> falta de ordem… falta de metodo… falta de atenção… falta de disciplina… trololó… tralalá… tudo no mesmo tom… na mesma tecla… e não soube dizer outra coisa esta manhã…

Os exemplos repetem-se no Google Books às dúzias até ao presente. Uns referem-se a música como [este de 1969](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zEBTAAAAMAAJ&q=trolol%C3%B3&dq=trolol%C3%B3&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEnqqZjdPQAhUFBBoKHXuqCfI4ZBDoAQiCATAQ); outros a jornalismo de encher [(exemplo de 1957)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YR0rAAAAIAAJ&q=trolol%C3%B3&dq=trolol%C3%B3&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEnqqZjdPQAhUFBBoKHXuqCfI4ZBDoAQi2AjAt) ou simplesmente a discurso chato cheio de lugares comuns [(exemplo de 1976)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BIwsAQAAMAAJ&q=trolol%C3%B3&dq=trolol%C3%B3&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie7Y6Dg9XQAhVD2xoKHXvRCt84ZBDoAQidAjAp).

Por vezes, esta noção parece aproximar-se algo de ‘cantiga para enganar’, como é o caso do “trololó petetista” do teu exemplo. Também isto já vem de trás. Por exemplo, Januário d’Allessio, antigo dirigente do Palmeiras, relatou à [*Placar* em 1979](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8PywSCsRWBsC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22depois%20desse%20trolol%C3%B3%22&source=bl&ots=Ok6R1tiuyY&sig=4gJqj6gUlFYRscOMi_1v4q0uq5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiqtvgr9jQAhVEtxoKHT2LCCsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22depois%20desse%20trolol%C3%B3%22&f=false) que um dos diretores do Universitário de Lima lhe sugeriu que o Palmeiras perdesse com o Universitário em Lima para assegurar estádio cheio mais tarde em São Paulo. Continua ele:

> Depois desse **trololó** todo quis saber qual era minha opinião, mas eu fingi não ter entendido bem e ele se mancou.

---

Há uma vaga associação com *troll*, mas é pré-internet: a série animada de Hanna Barbera *Trolkins* estreou em 1981 no Brasil sob o nome *A Família Trololó* [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trollkins).

E em 2010 um vídeo de um obscuro cantor russo, [Eduard Khil (Wkipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Khil), virou viral na internet; e como a sua canção era *lalalá, nananá, lololó* do princípio ao fim, ficou conhecido por cantor *trololó* [(Folha de São Paulo, 2010](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/livrariadafolha/ult10082u730157.shtml)). Nalguns [sites de língua inglesa](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22troll%20lol%20lol%22&oq=%22troll%20lol&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l3.5540j0j4), a canção aparece sob o nome *Troll* seguido dum número variável de *lols*, e daí a ligação entre *trololó* e *troll lol lol*. O Ramon explica na sua resposta que este vídeo originou em certos meios na internet um novo uso interjetivo de *trololó*,  mas a ligação ao uso dos teu exemplos é espúria: já antes do vídeo se falava do *trololó tucano* do teu segundo exemplo [(Veja, 2006)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22trolol%C3%B3%20tucano%22&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH5-6PttjQAhXGCBoKHRlCDL8Q_AUIDigA&biw=1242&bih=580) e já o José Serra do teu primeiro exemplo acusava isto e aquilo de ser *trololó de economista* e era por seu turno acusado de expelir *trololó de político* [(Veja, 2007)](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/reinaldo/geral/escandalo-familia-terrorista-lamarca-recebe-mais-r-1-milhao-em-indenizacao/).

Comment: A tua resposta faz sentido.   +1.  Mas ainda insisto que, no Brasil, deve ter se popularizado junto a uma determinada faixa etária ou algum grupo que tenha interesse naquilo que "bombou" no youtube.  Eu nunca ouvi.  Meus filhos também não.

Comment: @Centaurus O uso de *trololó* que o Ramon descreve é capaz de ser do mesmo género que o de [*Malaquias* para 'pénis'](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/por-que-malaquias-%C3%A9-um-termo-chulo-em-portugal); supostamente oriundo de Portugal, e até agora, que conhecessem, só encontrei o JorgeB.

Comment: Obrigado, @Jacinto. Acho que mataste a cobra.

Answer (score 3):

O significado mais contemporâneo de *trololó* é o aportuguesamento de um meme da internet. De acordo com o site [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trololo-russian-rickroll#fn7):

> *[Trololo](https://youtu.be/oavMtUWDBTM)* é um vídeo do cantor russo Eduard Khil, numa apresentação da canção popular soviética [*Я очень рад, ведь я, наконец, возвращаюсь домой*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF_%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4,_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) (*Estou Contente, Porque Finalmente Voltarei Para Casa*, em russo). Este vídeo popularizou-se como uma ferramenta de pegadinha, numa série de memes similares ao *[Rickrolling](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling)*.
>
> Como a canção inteira é puramente improvisada em [scat](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat), sem nenhuma letra ou sentido, o vídeo atraiu a atenção dos internautas ocidentais por conta da excentricidade.
>
> No dia 20 de dezembro de 2009, uma [seção do vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA) composta somente de risadas foi enviada ao site de vídeos *Youtube* pelo usuário *KamoKatt*, acumulando mais de 6 milhões de visualizações em três anos. Em 27 de janeiro de 2010, o vídeo foi postado no agregador de notícias *Reddit* pelo usuário *gn3xu5*, sob a etiqueta *WTF* (*Que Porra é Esta*, em inglês), com o título [*Trololololololololo*](http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/b31dc/trololololololololo/), recebendo mais de 600 votos positivos e 95 comentários. No dia 19 de fevereiro do mesmo ano, o blog BuzzFeed publicou o vídeo com o título de *[Lyrical Genius](http://www.buzzfeed.com/awesomer/lyrical-genius)* (*Gênio Literário*). Dois dias depois, o portal de notícias The Huffington Post incluiu o vídeo num artigo chamado *[Is This Weird Russian Guy the Best Lyricist of All Time? No](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trololo-russian-rickroll#fn7)* (*Este Russo Esquisito e o Melhor Letrista de Todos os Tempos? Não*). Uma semana depois, o site http://trololololololololololo.com/ foi lançado, reproduzindo o vídeo original automaticamente e em modo de repetição permanente. O site não está mais disponível na internet.
>
> A canção também foi tocada na [cerimônia de abertura dos Jogos Olímpicos de Inverno de 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYjO2VH3aYo), realizada na cidade russa de Sochi, na data de 7 de fevereiro de 2014.
>
> A popularidade do vídeo (e do meme a ele associado) foi renovada pela repercussão do falecimento trágico do cantor, que sofreu um acidente vascular cerebral em 28 de maio de 2012, falecendo uma semana depois, aos 77 anos, ainda hospitalizado, na cidade de São Petersburgo, Rússia. Eduard Khil foi chamado pela mídia, então, por *[Homem do Trololó](http://www.rferl.org/content/mr-trololo-hospitalized-after-suffering-stroke/24595519.html)*. O usuário *stoichkov* submeteu um post no *Reddit* [informando a comunidade do óbito](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/ujt71/eduard_khil_trololo_guy_dies_in_st_petersburg/), que rapidamente alcançou a capa do site após receber mais de 2 mil votos positivos em menos de 12 horas.

Então, respondendo à sua pergunta, **não é uma coincidência**: a expressão só se tornou popular justamente pelo meme justapor as palavras "*troll*" (mensagem provocativa, na linguagem cibernética) e "*LOL*" (risadas). Em especial, o trecho do vídeo que se tornou mais conhecido é justamente as risadas que o cantor inseriu no meio da improvisação. Claro que a música em si ter esta "letra" é uma coincidência, mas a etimologia do uso moderno de *trololó* está, sim, ligada à junção das palavras "*troll*" e "*LOL*". Embora a palavra em si já existisse antes da invenção da internet, este significado específico - o de **demonstração de humor a uma brincadeira** - é consequência direta do meme.

Comment: Qual é o significado mais contemporâneo de *trololó*, que referes no início da tua resposta? Podes ouvir a canção [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-bxeQ2ywfM): ouves lá muitos *lo-lo-ló*, mas "troll lol".

Comment: @Jacinto É uma demonstração de humor em reação a uma brincadeira ou "pegadinha". Não faz muito sentido fora do contexto cibernético, mas seria uma forma de dizer "muito engraçado, você é muito brincalhão".

Comment: A expressão tornou-se popular em que região do Brasil e junto a pessoas de que faixa etária?  Pergunto isso porque vivo na região sudeste e nunca ouvi.  Achei que fosse pelo fato de eu não ser jovem, e perguntei a meus filhos, que também nunca ouviram.

Comment: @Centaurus Imagino que em todo o Brasil, numa faixa etária bem específica de adolescentes e jovens adultos, e num contexto ainda mais específico de redes sociais e jogos eletrônicos. Não é algo que eu já tenha escutado alguém dizer pessoalmente.

Comment: Ramon, valeria a pena incluíres na resposta a informação acerca desse uso de *trololó*, idealmente com um exemplo real da internet. Estive a ouvir o vídeo outra vez. Não ouves lá nenhum *troll lol*: o mais próximo disso, antes da risada, é (com *r* à inglesa) *'ralalalá lalalá lalalá*. Mas houve depois quem lhe chamasse a canção *troll lol lol*.

Comment: @Centaurus só num contexto de utilizadores de internet. Alguém que dissesse "soltei um lol" ou "que engraçado, lolei!", poderia também dizer "trololol!" como reconhecimento de uma partida endiabrada, ou de alguém estar a ser "um pestinha". É gíria de *netizen*...

Comment: @RamonMelo Embora concorde contigo quando escreves que `não é uma coincidência`, acho que quando escreves `a etimologia da palavra trololó está, sim, ligada à junção das palavras "troll" e "LOL"` induzes as pessoas em erro. A palavra `trololó` é mais antiga que a internet, e por isso não faz sentido dizer que a sua etimologia está ligada a conceitos internetianos. O que eu acho, é que a palavra ganhou um novo sentido: e que, então, **um dos** sentidos dela tem origem (talvez etimologia?) na internet e nas palavras "troll" e "LOL".

Comment: Se quiseres, Ramon, posso tentar fazer uma edição que sublinhe esta... [picuinhice](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/picuinhice) da minha opinião. Não fiz essa edição diretamente, porque podias achar que mudava o sentido da tua resposta.

Comment: @ANeves fiz a edição. E não acho que seja picuinhice, tudo o que for possível para melhorar a resposta é sempre válido.

Comment: @ANeves é um verdadeiro gentleman do mundo virtual.

Comment: @RamonMelo acho que ficou muito melhor. :)